# pyspark casting missing struct in optional array for delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

We have some data stored in multiple delta tables (one table for each day) without specifiying a schema . Since there is an optional array included in the data, the delta tables now have an incompatible schema.

To unify the delta tables we want to apply a schema to all delta tables.

The correct shortened schema looks like

```
# target schema
schema = StructType(
    [
        ...,
        StructField(
            "extracostlist", 
            ArrayType(
                StructType(
                    [
                        StructField("linenumber", IntegerType(), True),
                        StructField("costtype", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("netamount", DecimalType(38,10), True),
                    ]
                ),
                True,
            ),
            True,
        ),
        ...
    ]
)
```

while some of the tables now have a schema like:

```
# missing structs in array in delta table
root
|-- ...
|-- extracostlist: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|-- ...
```

The original data is delivered as a json either an empty list or with the data included according to the schema described above.

```
{
    ...,
    "extraCostList": [],
    ...,
}
```

So far I tried to

- create a new DataFrame with the data of the delta table and specified schema
- create an empty DataFrame and union it with the delta table data
- cast the data

each without success.

Since there are multiple cases like this a "dynamic" fix using a target schema would be appreciated.